# How to Trigger Two Promises and Conditionally Wait For One?

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript, promise

For example: I'm on a "create new account" page for a website.  Before creating the account, I need to determine if the e-mail that is given is a junk e-mail (i.e. test@test.com).  I also need to determine if the account already exists, returning back a list of possible accounts that should be used instead of the new one (maybe the address already exists, etc.) These are defined as such:

```
function emailIsValid(): JQueryPromise<boolean> { ... }
function getPotentialDuplicates(): JQueryPromise<IDupResults> { ... }
```

Hypothetically, let's say the `getPotentialDuplicates` call has to check a really old database that's super slow, taking 3-5 seconds to finish, while the `emailIsValid` usually takes .4 seconds.  Therefore, I'd like to kick both of these calls off simultaneously with this results being defined by this action tree:

- If - `getPotentialDuplicates` returns first:

  - Wait for `emailIsValid` to return
  - If - email is valid:

    1. If - no dups are found, Create Account
    2. Else - show dups to user.
  - Else - Ignore dupResults and display "Email is Invalid"
- Else - `emailIsValid` returns First:

  - If - email is valid:

    1. Wait for `getPotentialDuplicates`
    2. If - no dups are found, Create Account
    3. Else - show dups to user.
  - Else - Don't wait for `getPotentialDuplicates` and display "Email is Invalid"

Currently I'm using `when.done` but this waits for both to finish. Is there a simple way of defining this?

Comment: I'm not sure that there's anything in the native Promise or jQuery's implementation that can do that. The bluebird promise library has [`Promise.any`](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.any.html) which seems to do what you want.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan is the native Promise implementation just the standard API definition for Promises, or is it a particular library?

Comment: Recent versions of browsers implement the Promise object natively, and generally conform to the [Promise/A+ standard](https://promisesaplus.com/). There are, of course, libraries which also implement that same standard, plus some extras, like [Q](https://github.com/kriskowal/q) and the aforementioned [bluebird](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/getting-started.html). jQuery's implementation, in 1.5, is "based on the [CommonJS Promises/A standard](http://wiki.commonjs.org/wiki/Promises/A)." See [jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.Deferred/).

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan I was planning to upgrade to the latest version of jQuery since I heard the Promises were "better".  I need to support IE10 (because this is all in MS CRM), and am currently using Typescript and requireJS.  Does that lend itself to any particular library?

Comment: Hmm... Not that I know of. You might want to check out the links to their respective sites for the browser support though.

Comment: After reading @basarat 's comment, and looking up the definition of pollyfilling on Wikipedia... I like the idea of being as native browser based as possible, which makes es6-promise a wonderful thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In both your cases you want to wait for `emailIsValid`. So :

```
// kick off both
const emailIsValidProm = emailIsValid();
const getPotentialDuplicatesProm = getPotentialDuplicates();

emailIsValidProm.then((res)=> {
     if (res.invalid) { // if res in valid
        return; 
     } 
     else {
       // now wait for the other 
       return getPotentialDuplicatesProm
     }
})
.then(res=> {
   if (!res) return; // email wasn't valid;
   // The res is for `getPotentialDuplicatesProm
   // USE it !
 })
```

PS: highly recommend not using Jquery promises and using standard Promise api. I have docs on the standard one : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/promise.html

Comment: I'm assuming by "standard Promise api", you mean a library that implements the standard?  If so, what library do you recommend when working with TypeScript?  I am using JQuery because I already have JQuery and didn't see the need to bring in something else new.  Can you direct me to something that would explain why JQuery (the seemingly king of all js libraries) is not recommended?

Comment: About Jquery promise being bad : https://gist.github.com/domenic/3889970 

About polyfilling promises : https://github.com/stefanpenner/es6-promise

Comment: I had no idea what Polyfilling was until this conversation.  Awesome!  Will use the es6-promise library!